# Setting style.backgroundColor shuts down code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on some form validation where I go through the elements in my form with a for (elem in myform) loop checking it against a list of required fields and set the background color to 'pink' if a required field has no value.

To reset the color to the default I set the property back to null at the beginning of the loop.

It works flawlessly, however for some strange reason it doesn't run my google script call after the loop. (or an alert I tried putting there)

Spent hours trying to figure out the cause commenting out bits and bits and ended up with this: If I remove the color resetting part.. the google script runs and everything works perfectly (except the color of the now already completed fields remains pink)

```
if(thisEl.style.backgroundColor == "pink")
        {
          thisEl.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
```

I even tried commenting out the actual value change and leaving just the if clause and still it doesn't work.. Somehow accessing that property makes prevents me from doing anything after the loop.

**Solution (rather workaround):** Some of my objects didn't have a style property and trying to access the backgroundColor of that threw an exception so I'm testing if the style property exists first with a if(thisEl.style != null)

Comment: Have you tried resetting the style with the null string `""` instead of `null`'? Also, what loop code?

Comment: @Traktor53 No I haven't, since like I said even if I comment out the line that sets the style, the if statement itself is causing the same issue. Also like I said in my question I have a for-in loop that cycles through every element of my form, validates it after which I call a google script and pass the form along for saving into my spreadsheet

Comment: I would suggest creating a minimal test case that allows readers to reproduce the problem. You may find including "use strict" at the beginning of the code (if not already there) produces more meaningful error messages.

Comment: @Traktor53 You're on to something here.. Console does log a type error and that it's trying to read the backgroundColor of undefined..

Comment: The reason that's strange is because I'm testing thisEl against null at the beginning of the loop and skipping the cycle with continue if it is.. It's also strange because it actually works in setting the colors.. I think the very last element it gets from the form is doing this like a char-set definition or something

Comment: I would question why you might test `thisEL` against `null` unless you set it to `null` somewhere. But without the code it is not possible to go further.

Comment: I "solved it" by testing if the style property of the element exists first and only then trying to set the backgroundColor.. It's kind of a workaround, I still don't know which one was causing the issues, but you helped me by pointing me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Are there radio buttons?  Groups of buttons are represented in form element collections as [RadioNodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList) objects which are not HTML elements and legitimately don't have style object properties. If so, please post your solution as an answer - it's not a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: Some of my objects didn't have a style property and trying to access the backgroundColor of that threw an exception so testing if the style property exists first with a if(thisEl.style != null) solved the issue.

Initially I didn't know why there were such objects, so credit goes to @Traktor53 for pointing out that radio button groups are represented as a RadioNodeList in the form element collection which doesn't have a style object property. (see comments for details)